# Optimization problem involving eigenvalue problem

Tags: analysis, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I want to find the ${\bf x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that minimizes a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. $f$ is not linear, but it can be broken down in the following way:

1. Let ${\bf v} \in \mathbb{R}^m$ be the solution (with $\|{\bf v}\| = 1$) to the eigenvalue problem $A({\bf x}){\bf v} = \lambda \mathbb{v}$ with the smallest eigenvalue (or in general, any solution to this eigenvalue problem), where $A$ is an $m \times m$ tridiagonal, symmetric matrix whose diagonal entries are continuous functions of ${\bf x}$, $A_{ii}: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ for $i = 1, ..., m$.
2. The objective function $f$ can then be written as $f({\bf x}) = (h \circ g)({\bf x})$, where $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ maps to ${\bf x}$ the solution ${\bf v}$ to the above eigenproblem, and crucially, $h: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear function.

Ideally, I would like the entire problem to be linear, in which case the question is whether there are additional assumptions under which the function $g$ is linear, and what these might be. In the more general case, what "desirable" properties (e.g. convexity) should I look for to make this problem more feasible?

Comment: Any multiple of $v$ also works, do you impose norm 1 on it ? also if the eigen space of the lowest eigen value is of dimension $\geq 2$ then which one do you choose ? do you have some notion of continuity on $g$ ? If so what kind of constraint is there on $A(x)$ then ?

Comment: @P.Quinton thanks, I've updated the question

Comment: Do you have any property on $A$ ? and are you looking at lowest eigen value or any eigen vector ?

Comment: @P.Quinton only that it is diagonal, all terms are zero except the ones on the main diagonal and the two diagonals nearest to the main diagonal, and as stated, the diagonal entries are continuous functions of ${\bf x}$. Ideally I want to look at the lowest eigenvector for simplicity: this is a numerical version of a Schrodinger problem where we are interested primarily in the ground states

Comment: Is the parameterization of $A(x)$ highly constrained beyond the banded structure? If not, an eigenvector $v$ parallel with $c$ would minimize the objective, meaning you can minimize $\lambda$ under $A(x)c=\lambda c$.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Sorry, could you clarify what you mean by banded structure? And what is $c$ in your notation?

Comment: Banded = tridiagonal. With c I mean the linear objective, $c^Tv$.